# Tinymce 4 file_browser_callback: Function for opening a local file browser

Tags: tinymce, image-uploading

I use Tinymce 4.0 on my web application. But I really don't know how to do this: when the user click on the browse button, how to open a local file browser and add an image URL to the dialog window from this local file browser? I have this source code:

```
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = ''; }
```

But I don' t know how to solve this problem. I don't need a special file browser but function for opening **local file browser**.

Comment: Isn't there a plugin that would do this? I've used HTML editors before - I think the last one was FKEditor - and there was a plugin for pretty much everything.

Comment: TinyMCE authors have created a plugin for this - [MoxieManager](http://www.moxiemanager.com/demos/tinymce.php), but it is a paid one.

Answer (score 0):

Here the snippet from [Basic Local File Picker](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/) demo from TinyMCE docs:

*Note: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work here as a StackOverflow snippet.*

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
  plugins: 'image code',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
  // enable title field in the Image dialog
  image_title: true, 
  // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
  automatic_uploads: true,
  // URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
  file_picker_types: 'image', 
  // and here's our custom image picker
  file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
    
    // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
    // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
    // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
    // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
    // once you do not need it anymore.

    input.onchange = function() {
      var file = this.files[0];
      
      // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
      // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
      // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
      var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
      var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
      var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
      blobCache.add(blobInfo);
      
      // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
      cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
    };
    
    input.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```